# How to use NSFormatter number for Persian or Arabic number in array in swift 3?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, nsnumberformatter

I know how to use NSFormatter Number for converting English numbers to Persian/Arabic numbers but the problem is that I have an Array and want to convert all of the numbers in the array to Persian/Arabic numbers.

How can I do that?
please help.

Here is the code for one number :

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa")
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal

    numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: checkNumber))
    let persianNumber = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: checkNumber))!
```

As you see, I can convert one number (checkNumber is English Number and persianNumber is Persian/Arabic Number)

Comment: You wan a new array? Or replace the value? Is your issue just about the for loop ?

Comment: I Just want to convert english numbers in array to persian numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create swift file and apend this extension

```
extension String {


 func englishToPersian() -> String{
    var sum = ""
    let letters = self.characters.map { String($0) }
    for letter in letters {
        if (Int(letter) != nil) {
            let persianNumber = ["۰","۱","۲","۳","۴","۵","۶","۷","۸","۹"]
            sum = sum+persianNumber[Int("\(letter)")!]
        } else {
            sum = sum+letter
        }
    }
    return sum
 }

 func persianToEnglish() -> String{
    var sum = ""
    let letters = self.characters.map { String($0) }
    let persianNumber = ["۰","۱","۲","۳","۴","۵","۶","۷","۸","۹"]
    for letter in letters {
        for (index, element) in persianNumber.enumerated() {
            if letter == element {
                sum = sum + "\(index)"
            }
        }
    }
    return sum
 }

}
```

use this

```
let strEnglish1 = "1234567890"
strEnglish1.englishToPersian() // ۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰

let strEnglish2 = "1200 toman"
strEnglish2.englishToPersian() // ۱۲۰۰ toman

let strPersian1 = "۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰"
strPersian1.persianToEnglish() // 1234567890

let strPersian2 = "۱۲۰۰  تومان"
strPersian1.persianToEnglish() // ۱۲۰۰  تومان
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think a simple for loop will do what you want.

The important thing is to get rid of the optional `String` that you get from the number formatter because you can't append optional strings (`String?`) to an array of strings (`[String]`). You can use the nil coalescing operator (`??`) to fallback to the empty string (`""`) when the result from the number formatter is `nil`.

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa")
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal

let arrayOfNumbers = [1, 2, 3]
var arrayOfStrings = [String]()

for number in arrayOfNumbers {
    let string = numberFormatter.string(from: number as NSNumber) ?? ""
    arrayOfStrings.append(string)
}
```

Even better, you could use the `map` function instead of a for loop.

```
let arrayOfStrings = arrayOfNumbers.map { (number) in
    return numberFormatter.string(from: number as NSNumber) ?? ""
}
```

Comment: thats it! it worked! thanks a lot ! please vote my question

Comment: please help me again to find the similar question answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627982/how-to-use-persian-numbers-in-uitextfield-in-swift-3