# how to use persian numbers in UItextField in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter, numberformatter

Hi I am using text field in my swift3 application - I want when user enter a number in the text field instead of english number textfield shows persian numbers - my textfield keyboard has set to just enter number so the user can't use text inside the text field with keyboard so here is my codes that doesn't work

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
 let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa")
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
    let cm:Int? = Int(englishNumber.text!)

    if cm != nil {
    numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: cm!))
    myTextField.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: cm!))!
    }
```

**remember that I used textfield Delegate and I want every Number that user entered change to Persian number and the user thought that writing Persian Numbers **

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 func convertEngNumToPersianNum(num: String)->String{
        let number = NSNumber(value: Int(num)!)
        let format = NumberFormatter()
        format.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa_IR")
        let faNumber = format.string(from: number)

        return faNumber!
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Posting a piece of code without any text is often not very helpful.

Comment: I know that how to convert english numbers into persian numbers the problem for me is I want while user editing text field this function happen

Comment: @NoelWidmer  convert english numbers into persian numbers